# ogr2ogr: 'ERROR 1: Wrong field type for ID' with primary key

Tags: postgis, postgresql, ogr, ogr2ogr

I have a shapefile with the following structure:

[image]

[image]

I'm trying using ogr2ogr to import the above shapefile inside my PostGIS database with the following code:

```
ogr2ogr -append -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost dbname=vector_data 
user=postgres password=postgres" 
grid.shp -a_srs EPSG:4326 -skipfailures -lco FID=ID 
-lco COLUMN_TYPES=ID=VARCHAR -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geom
```

The problem is when I run the above code, I get the following error message:

```
ERROR 1: Wrong field type for ID
```

I've understood the problem is because my ID field is a String and not an Integer, however I put `COLUMN_TYPES=ID=VARCHAR` on my script and ogr2ogr was not able to understand it.

I tried to import this shapefile using no field as FID and it worked, but I would like to import it in my database using ID as a primary key even it is a String.

Is there a way of doing it?

The shapefile is here: http://www.dpi.inpe.br/newcatalog/tmp/grades/grade_cbers4_mux.zip

Comment: In ArcGIS, "ID" is a *phantom* shapefile field -- it's just a row-number identifier (zero-based). If the dBase file actually has a field named "ID", it will get renamed to "ID_". You're much better off renaming the "ID" to be "MYID" than trying to change the type of a non-existant column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a workaround to this. I'm having the same problem and I just ended up leaving the generated FID column as is and created an unique index on the column I wanted to create the primary key on.

If you don't really need a primary key but just an index and/or a unique constraint then just go that way.

I found this link where it has been reported as an issue 5 years ago but the ticket is qualified as a "wontfix" and closed :
https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/5654

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and tips, I am going to follow them. The fact they won't fix this issue is really sad, because I believe this resource would be a great one to ogr2ogr.

Answer (score 2):

The specification:

```
-lco "FID=ID COLUMN_TYPES=ID=VARCHAR"
```

works in the incaration of ogr2ogr dated GDAL 3.0.4, released 2020/01/28.